# Finding image similarities in a folder of thousands

Tags: python

I've cobbled together/wrote some code (Thanks stackoverflow users!) that checks for similarities in images using imagehash, but now I am having issues checking thousands of images (roughly 16,000). Is there anything that I could improve with the code (or a different route entirely) that can more accurately find matches and/or decrease time required? Thanks!

I first changed my list that is created to an itertools combination, so it only compares unique combinations of images.

```
new_loc = os.chdir(r'''myimagelocation''')
dirloc = os.listdir(r'''myimagelocation''')

duplicates = []
dup = []

for f1, f2 in itertools.combinations(dirloc,2):
    #Honestly not sure which hash method to use, so I went with dhash.
    dhash1 = imagehash.dhash(Image.open(f1))
    dhash2 = imagehash.dhash(Image.open(f2))
    hashdif = dhash1 - dhash2


    if hashdif < 5:  #May change the 5 to find more accurate matches
            print("images are similar due to dhash", "image1", f1, "image2", f2)
            duplicates.append(f1)
            dup.append(f2)

    #Setting up a CSV file with the similar images to review before deleting
    with open("duplicates.csv", "w") as myfile:
        wr = csv.writer(myfile)
        wr.writerows(zip(duplicates, dup))
```

Currently, this code may take days to process the number of images I have in the folder. I'm hoping to reduce this down to hours if possible.

Comment: Just as a heads up, the line `with open("duplicates.csv", "w") as myfile:` will overwrite the duplicates.csv file every loop so you should move it out of the for loop

Comment: Ahh good catch! Thanks!

Comment: What kind of images -- content? graphics, line drawing or real world images? Color or grayscale? How large are the files?  It looks like you are doing the computation of hashing for every image against every other image. You could compute the hash for every image just once and store in a database or in the image meta data. Then just use the hash values to do the compare. That way you do not compute the hash multiple times for each image. There are other hashes that can be used. But they might be slower to get better quality matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, instead of hashing each image at comparison (127,992,000 hashes), you hash ahead of time and compare the hashes since those are not going to change (16,000 hashes).

```py
new_loc = os.chdir(r'''myimagelocation''')
dirloc = os.listdir(r'''myimagelocation''')

duplicates = []
dup = []

hashes = []

for file in dirloc:
    hashes.append((file, imagehash.dhash(Image.open(file))))

for pair1, pair2 in itertools.combinations(hashes,2):
    f1, dhash1 = pair1
    f2, dhash2 = pair2
    #Honestly not sure which hash method to use, so I went with dhash.
    hashdif = dhash1 - dhash2


    if hashdif < 5:  #May change the 5 to find more accurate matches
            print("images are similar due to dhash", "image1", f1, "image2", f2)
            duplicates.append(f1)
            dup.append(f2)

#Setting up a CSV file with the similar images to review before deleting
with open("duplicates.csv", "w") as myfile: # also move this out of the loop so you arent rewriting the file every time
    wr = csv.writer(myfile)
    wr.writerows(zip(duplicates, dup))
```

Comment: This looks perfect, reducing the number of computations required, but I received an error.    image = image.convert("L").resize((hash_size + 1, hash_size), Image.ANTIALIAS)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'convert'

Comment: Which line of code is throwing this error? The `imagehash.dhash(Image.open(file))` line?

Comment: Yep, that line.  hashes.append((file, imagehash.dhash(file)))

Comment: Did hashing the images work in the example you provided?

Comment: I tested it on a smaller folder of images to verify it would find a duplicate. It's not as accurate as I would like, but it's a start.

Comment: Does my code work on the same folder of images? I am not sure what would cause that error (other than potentially a bad image?). I called it the same way you did, just storing the hash differently.

Comment: I may have misunderstood. I haven't gotten your code to work just yet for my smaller test folder (haven't tried larger folder).

Comment: I figured it out. I had to add the Image.open part, I was missing it.